# Editing Individual Bar Colors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am writing a sample code in MATLAB to display profit of a business over a certain amount of time. So far I have plotted the following with relative ease.

```
time = {'4 weeks','12 weeks','24 weeks','27 weeks'};

profit= [-4.9,-4.75,-2.49,4.5];

g=bar(profit)

set(gca,'XTick',1:4,'XTickLabel',x)
```

However, I would like negative values to display red and positive bar values to display green. I tried using

```
set(g(1),'facecolor','r')
```

To see if I could manually do it considering my x values were pretty small and doing it manually wouldn't be a problem. However, I keep getting error messages saying it is inappropriate to set g=bar(profit). What is the best way to set this up? I know it would probably help to set a for loop and if the value of time(n) < 1 -> red and time(n) > 1 -> green, but I can't seem to get it down with the syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it, you could separate your positive and negative values.

```
time = {'4 weeks','12 weeks','24 weeks','27 weeks'};

profit= [-4.9,-4.75,-2.49,4.5];

profit_pos = profit.*(profit>0); % positive profit
profit_neg = profit.*(profit<=0); % negative profit

figure
g=bar(profit_pos,'b'); % plots positive in blue
hold on
bar(profit_neg,'r') % plots negative in red
set(gca,'XTick',1:4,'XTickLabel',x)
```

The `profit_pos` and `profit_neg` are the two new variable.s The element-wise multiplication for the logical array gets the positive and negative values in the two variables. This also works for an array with any size and does not need a for loop.